# A Python script that will reverse the characters in a txt file and put them in a new file

Tags: python

I am trying to code a Python script that will reverse the characters in a txt file and put them in a new file, but it always leaves out the first line of the characters and joins the last 2 lines together. What is wrong? Thank you in advance ^^

```
def main():
    fp = open( "pc_writetest.tmp", "w" )
    hello = open("pc_rose.txt")
    add = ""
    text = hello.readline()
    while True:
        text = hello.readline()
        for i in range(len(text)-1, -1, -1):
            add += str(text[i])
        if text == "":
            fp.writelines(add)
            break
    fp.close()
    fp = open( "pc_writetest.tmp" )
    buffer = fp.read()
    fp.close()
    print( buffer )
```

Comment: Well, have you tried rubber duck debugging? You read a line, then you enter the `while` loop and read another line (and reassign the name `text`). Of course the first line will be lost.

Comment: Hi Tim! Bear with me- I'm just a beginner. I'll give that a shot though. Thanks!

Comment: It would also be helpful to show your test file and the corresponding output.

Comment: `with open("pc_rose.txt") as f:
  res = f.read()[::-1]`

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned you accidentally read the first line, but then throw it away, so it never reaches your reversed string. This should be a working solution:

```
def main():
    fp = open( "reverse", "w" )
    hello = open("correct")
    add = ""
    while True:
        text = hello.readline()
        for i in range(len(text)-1, -1, -1):
            add += str(text[i])
        if text == "":
            fp.writelines(add)
            break
    fp.close()
    fp = open("reverse")
    buffer = fp.read()
    fp.close()
    print( buffer )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I also wanted to show you something cool with Python. Given any iterable (a string, a list, etc.) you can reverse it very easily.

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
print(l[::-1]) # prints [3, 2, 1]
```

So your entire program can be written in just two lines!

```
def main():
    with open('reverse', 'w') as r_fp, open('correct', 'r') as c_fp:
        r_fp.write(c_fp.read()[::-1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi Axel! Thanks for answering. That 2-liner is pretty neat- will try it after I finish fixing my little script here. And now the scoreboard is Everyone- 10000 Me- 0.

Comment: @BD No problem! I believe it's always important to figure out the long way, get it correct, and be comfortable with it before using Python hacks. That way if you go to another language where something like this isn't possible, you still know the solution. So make sure you're comfortable with the first answer!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that is wrong is that you read the first line, enter the loop, read the second line, and then point the variable `text` to the new line, losing the reference to the first.

The second thing is that the last line you read, probably doesn't end with a new line character `\n` so when you write it backwards it joins with the previous line.

Also note that it is [good practice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to use `with` to deal with file object

Comment: Hi bpbutti! Woah- how careless of me. Thanks for answering!!